# Date JSON Parsing form

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am parsing this JSON :

```
{
 "poster_path":"\/vZpB8ezB1IqpxI9rx553TuGwDzJ.jpg",
 "overview":"Thirty years after defeating the Galactic Empire, Han Solo and his allies face a new threat from the evil Kylo Ren and his army of Stormtroopers.",
 "release_date":"2015-12-15",
 "genre_ids":[  ],
 "id":140607,
 "original_title":"Star Wars: The Force Awakens",
 "original_language":"en",
 "title":"Star Wars: The Force Awakens",
 "vote_average":7.65
}
```

and I could parse all the attributes I want

```
overview=movieForecast.getString(OVERVIEW);
original_title = movieForecast.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
movie_poster= movieForecast.getString(POSTER_PATH);
user_rating = movieForecast.getDouble(VOTE_AVERAGE);
release_date  = movieForecast.getInt(RELEASE_DATE);
```

but I had a problem with the user_rating and the release date , but I was able to fix to the user_rating by changing getString method to getDouble

but I couldn't do the same with the release date nothing work with it (getDouble,getInteger , getString) nothing !

Comment: `String release_date  = movieForecast.getString("release_date");` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your release_date is a `Date` object.
If it is, you can use `SimpleDateFormatter`.

---

```
String date = movieForecast.getString("release_date");
SimpleDateFormatter sdf = new SimpleDateFormatter("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date releaseDate = sdf.parse(date);

movieForecast.setDate(releaseDate); //example
```